# Accessing Action Filter's data in Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[ApiBasicAuthorize]
public ActionResult SignIn()
{

}
```

I have this custom filter called ApiBasicAuthorize. Is it possible to access ApiBasicAuthorize's data (properties etc) inside the controller action SignIn?

If not, how do I pass data from the filter to controller action?

Comment: which method are you overriding in authrize_Attribute. you can add data to route dictionary, show us some more code of yours.

Comment: I am overriding OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) method.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a dictionary called items attached to the HttpContext object.  Use this dictionary to store items shared across components during a request.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Items["key"] = "Save it for later";

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

Then anywhere in your code later in the request...

```
var value = HttpContext.Current.Items["key"];
```

Comment: Even Praveen's answer works, but I have marked this as an answer because HttpContext.Items is more appropriate for this purpose instead of RouteData.Values

Comment: @goths - Hi, could you please explain why you chose `HttpContext.Items` over `RouteData`? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1809541/538387 Thanks

Comment: Hi @goths, yes I also am curious why the former is more "appropriate" than the latter?  It seems like they're both serving the same purpose, so wondering what limitations or intentions separate the two?

Comment: Question. Is the HttpContext.Items value is threadsafe. is  If I use the Custom Filter attribute in multiple actions and call it at the same time, how do we make sure the the right controller action will get the right data?

Answer (score 6):

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var rd = filterContext.RouteData;

        //add data to route
        rd.Values["key"]="Hello";

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }



public ActionResult(string key)
{
 //key= Hello
return View();
}
```