# How to get the request processing time in Asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I want to log the request processing time for *Asp.Net MVC application*. I can get '*time-taken*' from IIS  logs but this time includes the network time taken to send the response back to client browser. I am only interested in the time taken to preocess the request by asp.net worker process.

I have an option of writting a *HttpModule* but I can not control the order of running of HttpModules.

**Update - 1**:

I need to log the processing-time for all the requests. The requests are  slow only for some users which I am not able to reproduce when I request the page. 'MiniProfiler' and 'Glimpse' will not give me the 'procssing-time' for all the requests by different users.

**Update - 2**:

Filters will give me 'time-taken' only by Controller. It will not cover the 'time-taken' by various 'HttpModules' pluged in into the Asp.Net app

Comment: Ok, what's the meaning of "I can not control the order of running of HttpModules", HttpModules are executed in the order in which they were registered. http://forums.asp.net/t/1101427.aspx

Comment: @Donald: There are many HttpModules which are inherited from applicationHost.config. I dont want to touch that as there are many other web app deployed on the same server

Comment: as you can see in link, all httpmodules that are defined in the machine.config file, will be executed first. If you don't want it, you can remove it. Or if you want to re-order it, remove it, add your own, then add it back in your Web.config.

Answer (score 1):

One simple option would be to use something like [Miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/). There's documentation that shows you how to tie it into MVC properly.

However, if this type of metric is truly meaningful to track long term, I'd suggest looking into something like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/), or any other APM (application performance monitoring) solution.

You can also check out [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/). It doesn't so much log as just show you all the pertinent statistics as you browse around. It's also more suited to development than running on a production server, though you can potentially run it in production if you choose.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter to intercept action execution time.

```
 public class ActionTiming :ActionFilterAttribute {
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("TimingLogger");
    private string controllerName = string.Empty;
    private string actionName = string.Empty;

    private Stopwatch intertime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        intertime.Restart();
        controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var message = string.Format("{0} controller: {1} action: {2}", "OnActionExecuting", controllerName, actionName);
        Logger.Info(message);

    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

        var message = string.Format("{0} controller: {1} action: {2}, time (ms): {3}", "OnResultExecuted", controllerName, actionName, intertime.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Logger.Info(message);
    }


}
```

Then, you can register this filter globally in Application_Start or use it as attribute.

Comment: Apologizes but i need to downvote. It is not guaranteed that the instantiation of the actionFilter will happen for each request, making this solution unreliable. Use 'actionContext.Request.Properties' instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28885099/1754152, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22553930/1754152

Comment: Don't apologize please. Just explain why and when an actionfilter filter, registered globally for all action, don't execute.