# webapi actionfilters, how to inject a value when using different argument types that inherit from a base type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I have a base request type..

class RequestBase

```
{
   public string inputId;
   public string derivedid;
}
```

and types that inherit ..

```
class RequestA : RequestBase
{
   public string name;
}
```

and

```
class RequestB : RequestBase
{
   public string color;
}
```

I have a webapi service, some actions take an input parameter of RequestA, some take RequestB

```
[HttpPost]
 [MyFilter]
 [ActionName("Process1")]
  public HttpResponseMessage Process1(RequestA request)
  {  
      //do something with request.derivedId
  }

 [HttpPost]
 [MyFilter]
 [ActionName("Process2")]
  public HttpResponseMessage Process2(RequestB request)
  {  
      //do something with request.derivedId
  }
```

I have an actionfilter that takes the inputId from the request and generates a derivedId

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        RequestBase request = (RequestBase)actionContext.ActionArguments["request"];
        string inputId = request.inputId;

        string derivedId = inputId + "123";
        // ?? somehow inject derivedId back into the actionContext so that my controller methods can access?
    }
```

As my comment states above, I'd like to populate the derivedId field and have it accessible to my controller methods.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's a few solutions to this problem already described in this thread - one of them should suit you:

[ASP.NET MVC Pass object from Custom Action Filter to Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809042/asp-net-mvc-pass-object-from-custom-action-filter-to-action)