# How do I pass parameters from action filters to the controllers actions in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

It has been a day trying to figure out how to pass parameters from action filter to the controllers actions but with no luck. I have been to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809042/asp-net-mvc-pass-object-from-custom-action-filter-to-action) SO question and tried both of the answers. 
When I debug my application I don't get a value for my controller action parameter it is always null.

Here is the action filter...

```
public class FacebookCheckPermission : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string redirectURL { get; set; }
        public async  override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
                var myBaseController = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;
                PermissionRequestViewModel permissionViewModel = myBaseController.GetMissingPermissions();

                filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("Value1", "Hi");

                filterContext.ActionParameters["Value2"] = "Bye";

                if (permissionViewModel != null &&
                    permissionViewModel.MissingPermissions.Count > 0)
                //Code removed for brevity.

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }
```

And here is the Controller Action:

```
[FacebookCheckPermission]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string Value1, string Value2)
{
```

**UPDATE**
Seems that I have found the problem. The problem is that my Action filter is `async` and I have some API calls to facebook. I can get my action filter parameter if I declare it anywhere before the API calls but when I declare it under an API call my action parameter become null. What could be the problem?

Here is the call to facebook graph API.
dynamic myInfo = await `fb.GetTaskAsync("me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,link,locale,email,name,birthday,gender,location,age_range,about".GraphAPICall(appsecret_proof));`

Comment: That is just for example the real string names are different from ones I written here any ways I'll change it

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: In update you ask another question, I suggest check the answers if that useful for your question accept it, and ask another question with proper title and body, that's the way Stackoverflow recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RouteData values.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("MyParam", "ParamValue");
}
```

Then in the controller.

```
   var paramValue = RouteData.Values["MyParam"].ToString();
```

There is a "clunkier" method... I've put a private var at the top of the controller, assigned to this in OnActionExecuting and then used that var in my action method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wheels73, The question is updated please have a look and lemme know if you can help

Answer (score -1):

Use ActionParameters

```
 public class FacebookCheckPermission : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string redirectURL { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.ActionParameters["Value1"] = "Hi";
            filterContext.ActionParameters["Value2"] = "Bye";

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

    }

        [FacebookCheckPermission]
        public Task<ActionResult> Index(string Value1, string Value2)
        {
            string lol = $"{Value1} - {Value2}";
            return null;

        }
```

Use simple adding ActionParameters first, that works fine, then add other codes, there is not any problem with *ActionParameters*.

Comment: What is the $ sign? I never used it in MVC?

Comment: @Dawar It is C# 6 feature for string.format() you can use string.forma() I just want to check the values passed correct - string lol = string.Format("{0} - {1}", Value1, Value2);

Comment: But if the parameter values become null how can I access those values inside the action?

Comment: @Dawar When you use filterContext.ActionParameters["Value1"] = "Hi"; in ActionFilter that is not null, just in case that you passed the null value like: filterContext.ActionParameters["Value1"] = null;

Comment: Saeid, The question is updated please have a look and tell me if you can help.