# ASP.NET WebAPI - Pass object from Custom Action Filter to Action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

As per this question here, [ASP.NET MVC Pass object from Custom Action Filter to Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809042/asp-net-mvc-pass-object-from-)

, (which is for MVC), is there a similar object that we can add items or values to from within

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
}
```

, (which is for WebAPI), and access it seconds later in the Controller's action method itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

**set data:**

```
public class MyAwesomeFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //add stuff here.. to be accessed later
        actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("myKey69", myValue);

    }       
}
```

**retrieve data:**

```
[MyAwesomeFilter]
public IHttpActionResult MyController( [FromBody] string myParmStr ) {

    //retrieve the obj you inserted in filter...
    obj myValue = null;
    if (Request.Properties.TryGetValue("myKey69", out myValue)) {
        //logic here...
    }

}
```

Comment: Now would anyone like to try this for dotnet core, and post a similar answer? Or is it exactly the same?

Comment: I am using v4.8, and I am getting 'LogActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong instance of ActionFilterAttribute. I was using the one from Mvc instead of System.Web.Http.Filters